# Addition on the Zermelo Ordinals

Tags: logic, set-theory

How is addition defined using the Zermelo ordinals?

If you have a link to where it is defined, that would be equally appreciated.

Comment: How are you defining an infinite Zermelo ordinal?

Comment: Can you please address Reveillark's question? Are you only interested in finite ordinals? Or do you have some definition of infinite Zermelo ordinals in mind?

Comment: @AlexKruckman I am only interested in finite ordinals for the definition of addition, but this is from a larger interest in wanting to know the exact details in what goes wrong with using Zermelo ordinals in the transfinite. Any references to a detailed explanation of this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Actually, I think I see it now. Each Zermelo ordinal is defined as containing the previous one as its only element. I am not sure how you would define $\omega$ since there is no largest finite number. This doesn't happen with Von-Neumann ordinals because the are defined as containing all the ordinals before it so $\omega$ is just the set containing all the finite ordinals. Is this correct?

Comment: @ElGalloNegro Yes, that's exactly right. That's not to say you couldn't extend the Zermelo ordinals into the transfinite - for example, you could define a limit Zermelo ordinal to be the set of all Zermelo ordinals less than it - but this leads to much less elegant arguments and definitions than in the case of von Neumann ordinals.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Have there been any successful attempts to get around this issue?

Comment: @ElGalloNegro yes: the introduction of the von Neumann ordinals :0p

Comment: @AlexKruckman Haha, damn it. I had a feeling you would say that. Alright, I'll take that as a no then.

Comment: More seriously, it's not clear why you would want to. The role of the ordinals is to serve as representatives for well-orderings up to isomorphism. So for most purposes, the particular way they are interpreted in set theory is irrelevant: If you pick some way of extending the Zermelo natural numbers into the transfinite, then every Zermelo ordinal will be isomorphic to a von Neumann ordinal and vice versa. So anything you can do with one, you can do with the other: for example it's easy to define $+$ on the Zermelo natural numbers just as in J.G.'s answer.

Comment: Of course, sometimes when doing set theory it's useful to have a fixed interpretation of the ordinals, and here the von Neumann definition has a lot of nice properties, for example that the ordering relation on ordinals coincides with $\in$, and that the rank of an ordinal $\alpha$ (the least $\beta$ such that $\alpha\subseteq V_\beta$) is $\alpha$. Do the Zermelo natural numbers have some property that makes you prefer them to the von Neumann natural numbers?

Comment: @AlexKruckman But if you want Zermelo ordinals to be isomorphic to well orders then you can’t define them to be singletons…

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku yes, I should have said that for each Zermelo ordinal $\alpha$, the ordered set of all Zermelo ordinals less than $\alpha$ is isomorphic to the von Neumann ordinal $\alpha$.

Answer (score 2):

For von-Neumann ordinals we define $\alpha+\beta$ for fixed $\alpha$ as a function of $\beta$ by transfinite recursion on the latter. In particular$$\alpha+0:=\alpha,\,\alpha+\beta^+=(\alpha+\beta)^+,\,\alpha+\gamma:=\bigcup_{\beta\in\gamma}(\alpha+\beta)$$for nonzero limit ordinals $\gamma$, where $\beta^+:=\beta\cup\{\beta\}$. Since $1+\omega=\omega\ne\omega+1$, $+$ doesn't commute.

For Zermelo ordinals $\alpha_Z,\,\beta_Z$ isomorphic to Von Neumann ordinals $\alpha_W,\,\beta_W$, define $\alpha_Z+\beta_Z$ to be isomorphic to $\alpha_W+\beta_W$.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify, but I was asking for the definition with the Zermelo ordinals that did not appeal to the Von-Nuemann ordinals.